# Find the closed form for the double sum $ \sum_{1\leq j \leq k \leq n }3^k=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{j=k}^n 3^k$

Tags: summation

Find the closed form for the double sum

$$ \sum_{1\leq j \leq k \leq n }3^k$$

Here is my attempt:

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{j=k}^n 3^k $$

What should I do next to get the closed form? Please help me

Comment: What is your attempt? Also, please do not post images, but use the integrated MathJax-formula processor (e.g. using $\LaTeX$ commands)

Comment: Should $j$ appear in the summand?  If not, this becomes $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} k 3^k$ since each term $3^k$ appears $k$ times, once for each $1 \leq j \leq k$.

Comment: I just edited my question and posted my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1

We will use several times the formula
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{1 - q^{n+1}}{1 - q} \qquad (q\neq 1).
$$
We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leqslant j\leqslant k\leqslant n} 3^k
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{k=j}^n 3^k \right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( 3^j \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} 3^k \right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n 3^j \frac{1 - 3^{n-j+1}}{1 - 3} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n (3^{n+1} - 3^j) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( n3^{n+1} - 3\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 3^j \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( n3^{n+1} + \frac{3}{2}(3^n - 1) \right) \\
&= \frac{(2n-1)3^{n+1} + 3}{4}.
\end{align*}
$$

## Method 2

Note that 
$$
\sum_{1\leqslant j\leqslant k\leqslant n} 3^k = \sum_{k=1}^n k3^k.
$$
For all real $x\neq 1$, we have
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x - x^{n+1}}{1 - x}.
$$
Take the derivative with respect to x,
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1} = \frac{nx^{n+1} - (n+1)x^n + 1}{(1-x)^2},
$$
then multiply by $x$,
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n kx^k = \frac{nx^{n+2} - (n+1)x^{n+1} + x}{(1-x)^2},
$$
and finally put $x = 3$,
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n kx^k 
  = \frac{3n\times 3^{n+1} - (n+1)3^{n+1} + 3}{4}
  = \frac{(2n - 1)3^{n+1} + 3}{4}.
$$